# How to get extension attributes in product list by using api in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api, qty

I am using "http://localhost/rest/V1/products" api to get product details but not able to get product quantity in response.

So I searched and found that we can get product quantity with extension attributes. 
eg. extension_attributes": {
    "logo size": "small",
    "stock_item" : {
      "status" : "in_stock"
      "quantity": 70
    }
  }
but these are not showing in API response. I am using admin token for authentication.

Comment: Could you please let us know the exact Magento version you are using ?

Comment: I am using magento 2.2 CE

Answer (score 1):

To get any information about product inventory you must use API from CatalogInventory module.

There are two ways to tackle your problem

> 1. Using "`/V1/stockItems/:productSku`" endpoint to get Inventory Information for each individual product.
> 2. Code Customising to create a new endpoint for your need. Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155518/77673) link to know more about creating new endpoint.

Hope it finds helpful.