# Magento 2 - Get all details in product list api

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api

Is it possible to get **`product available quantity`** and **`ordered product quantity`** to get product API 
`http://localhost/test/rest/V1/products` with all other details?

And `extension_attributes` are also not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below URL.

[Geting the available quantity for all products via REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155361/geting-the-available-quantity-for-all-products-via-rest-api)

its related to your requirement which providing to available quantity for all products via REST API.

**I hope its very helpful to you.**